# google fit app to sync to fit.google.com (raspberry pi, Google Fit REST API)

Tags: android, python, google-fit

I would like to track steps on raspberry pi trough Google Fit REST API and act upon step count....

Because of the price and availability I got mi band which sync trough mi fit to google fit app (mobile phone), but data will get to the fit.google.com web just few times a day. So data (mi fit app to fit.google.com web) is delayed even 5h. Which is not really suited for daily tracking.

https://developers.google.com/fit/overview
I think I understand why google divided web and android fit API and why it might intentionally not sync to google fitness store more often. But it is a mess.

questions:

1. can I somehow force google fit app to sync to fit.google.com more often?
2. is there a work around? or google is the only one who can fix it?
3. any suggestion on wearable step counter with hourly update API database? eliminating google fit. Fitbit forces GPS to sync to android, so fitbit is battery drain. Garmin API, I have not tested.

thanks